# How to install Android SDK Platform on Mac?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, platform-agnostic

Whenever I try to install SDK Platform I am getting the following error:

[image: random screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried searching for the error on the web?

Comment: yes i did but i haven't found any solution

Comment: Try pasting that URL into your browser and see if you can reach it manually. I suspect you have a connection or a firewall problem.

Answer (score 1):

Read timed out 200 OK usually means that the issue is due to your internet connection.If it's urgent you can try downloading the zip file using your download manager and installing the sdk manually it's not hard you can follow this link if not you can try again later.[how-to-install-sdk-packages-offline-after-download-is-complete](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102955/how-to-install-sdk-packages-offline-after-download-is-complete)

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try and come back.